# What is a proper way to handle exceptions thrown by typeahead/Bloodhound code?

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

If data is not available in server or server error occurs or server data is null javascript throws exception `obj is null`. How to catch this exception?

Search in stackoverflow did not give any results.

Here's the code:

```
var test1 = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: "http://URL?query=",

        replace: function(url, query) {
            return url + "" + query;
        }
    }
});

test1.initialize();

$('#idOfAutoCompleteTextBox').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'test1',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: test1.ttAdapter()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is solution for your problem, but currently I have the same javascript exception when handling empty result (typeahead 0.11.1).

In the remote URL file when array is empty, echo something that is not in JSON format.

JavaScript

```
  var termekek = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('megnev'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: _BASE_ +  'components/com_rexwebshop/include/keres.php?q=%QUERY',
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
  });

  jQuery('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'rs3ws-termekek',
    display: 'megnev',
    source: termekek,
      templates: {
        empty: [
          '<div class="empty-message">',
            '<? echo JTEXT::_('Nincs találat') ?>',
          '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{megnev}}</strong> – {{bruttoar}}</div>')
      }
  });
```

PHP

```
  // [collecting data]

  if ( count($rows) == 0 ) 
    echo "_NOT_FOUND_";
  else
    echo json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this might help solve the problem in the original poster's question? I don't quite follow you.

Comment: remote php's source is not present in the question, so I could not give an exact solution